# System of non-autonomous coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Background:** I'm trying to analytically determine the time evolution of a qubit state given an Hamiltonian $H \propto \omega \sigma_z$ and error channels for all possible erros ($\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z$) with given error rates $\gamma_x, \gamma_y $ and $\gamma_z$. For $z$-errors I further differentiate excitation ($\propto \gamma_z n_{th}$) and de-excitation ($\propto \gamma_z (n_{th}+1)$). After costructing and solving the corresponding Lindblad master equation I end up with the following equations of motion for the states' bloch vector components (in the interaction picture):
$$
    \frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}  =\left[ -\gamma_z(2n_{th}+1)-4(\gamma_y + (\gamma_x-\gamma_y)\sin^2(\omega t))\right] x(t)+2\sin(2\omega t)(\gamma_x-\gamma_y)y(t)\\
    \frac{\text{d}y(t)}{\text{d}t}  =\left[ -\gamma_z(2n_{th}+1)-4(\gamma_y + (\gamma_x-\gamma_y)\cos^2(\omega t))\right] y(t)+2\sin(2\omega t)(\gamma_x-\gamma_y)x(t)\\
    \frac{\text{d}z(t)}{\text{d}t}  =-2\gamma_z((2n_{th}+1)z(t)-1)-4(\gamma_x+\gamma_y) 
$$
Solving for $z(t)$ is possible, but I haven't found a way to solve the equations for $x$ and $y$...

**Problem:** Solve the system of non-autonomous coupled differential equations:
$$
    \frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}  =\left[ b + 2a\sin^2(\omega t)\right] x(t)+a\sin(2\omega t)y(t)\\
    \frac{\text{d}y(t)}{\text{d}t}  =\left[ b + 2a\cos^2(\omega t)\right] y(t)+a\sin(2\omega t)x(t)
$$
I tried simple decoupling by substituting $u(t) = x(t) + c\cdot y(t)$ for some $c$ but this only works for the case $\omega t = \pi / 4$ ...

Generally, I have not much experience with more advanced differential equations. Is there a strategy or trick to solve them?

Comment: Have you tried to square them and add them? Not sure it works here but it sometimes does for this type of symmetrical equations.

Comment: I just tried it.. some of the mixed terms doe simplify but most terms don't.

Comment: What happens if you differentiate again? Also the quantity $xy$ has nicer dynamics than $x^2+y^2$ but still not completely helpful.

Comment: There is also physics.stackexchange.com or quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Define $p = x+y$ and $q=x-y$. Now first add equations and then subtract them to get

$$
\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t} + \frac{\text{d}y(t)}{\text{d}t} =\left[ b + a\sin(2\omega t)\right]\left( x+y\right) +2a\sin^2(\omega t)(x-y)+2ay\\
\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t} - \frac{\text{d}y(t)}{\text{d}t}  = \left[ b + a\sin(2\omega t)\right]\left( x-y\right) +2a\sin^2(\omega t)(x+y)-2ay
$$

In other words

$$
\frac{\text{d}p(t)}{\text{d}t} =\left[ b + a\sin(2\omega t)\right]p +2a\sin^2(\omega t)q+2ay\\
\frac{\text{d}q(t)}{\text{d}t}   = \left[ b + a\sin(2\omega t)\right]q +2a\sin^2(\omega t)p-2ay
$$

Again add these two equations to get

$$
\frac{\text{d}\left(p(t) + q(t)\right)}{\text{d}t} = \left[ b + a\sin(2\omega t) + 2a\sin^2(\omega t)\right](p+q)
$$

Now introduce $\gamma = p+q$ and solve equation

$$\frac{\text{d}\gamma}{\text{d}t} = \left[ b + a\sin(2\omega t) + 2a\sin^2(\omega t)\right]\gamma$$

Like this

$$\ln \gamma = bt - \frac{a}{2\omega}\cos(2\omega t) + at - \frac{a}{4\omega}\sin(4\omega t) + c$$

where $c$ is the constant of integration. Now remember that $\gamma = p+q = (x+y) + (x-y) = 2x$ and therefore $x = \frac{(a+b)t}{2} - \frac{a}{4\omega}\cos(2\omega t) - \frac{a}{8\omega}\sin(4\omega t) + c'$. Finally replace this in one of the main equations and solve for $y(t)$.

================================ Edit =============================

You can actually decouple easily but it involves a little bit linear algebra. I was trying to show a simple way to solve it above, but now I realized you need to decouple the variables. Consider the system

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x}\\ \dot{y} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b + 2a\sin^2(\omega t) & a\sin(2\omega t)\\ a\sin(2\omega t) & b + 2a\cos^2(\omega t) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y \end{bmatrix}
$$

If you want the system to be decoupled, you need to introduce a linear map that diagonalizes the system matrix

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} b + 2a\sin^2(\omega t) & a\sin(2\omega t)\\ a\sin(2\omega t) & b + 2a\cos^2(\omega t) \end{bmatrix}
$$

Notice that the system matrix can be written as (eigenvalue decomposition)

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}  \cos(\omega t) &\sin(\omega t)\\ -\sin(\omega t) &\cos(\omega t) \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} b & 0\\ 0 & 2a+b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  \cos(\omega t) &\sin(\omega t)\\ -\sin(\omega t) &\cos(\omega t) \end{bmatrix}^T
$$

Since $\det(A) = b(b+2a)$ and $\text{tr}(A) = 2b+2a$ and you can solve the system of equations $\lambda_1 + \lambda_1 = 2b+2a$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = b(b+2a)$ to find the eigen values $\lambda_1 = b$, $\lambda_2 = 2a+b$ and consequently the eigen vectors. If you want the system to always have EVD (i.e. the system matrix be diagonalizable, or equivalently, the system can be decoupled) then we must have $b(b+2a) > 0$ and $2a+2a \neq 0$, since the system matrix is symmetric already.

Therefore from EVD we find that the linear map that decouples the system is

$$
\begin{cases}x = \cos(\omega t)u + \sin(\omega t)v \\ y = -\sin(\omega t) u + \cos(\omega t)v \end{cases}
$$

Substitute $(x,y)$ in terms of $(u,v)$ in the main equations and get the decoupled system in terms of $(u,v)$. In the $u-v$ coordinate system, the equations will be decoupled.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, it helped me a lot! 
Nevertheless, when I try to decouple in the $(u,v)$ system, I always end up with 
$$
\frac{\text{d}(u-v)}{\text{d}t}=b(u-v)-\omega (u+v)-2av .
$$
I tried to do an EDV again for the corresponding equations 
$$
\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}t} = bu-\omega v \\
\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t} = (b+2a)v+\omega u
$$
but here it seems to be impossible to diagonalize the corresponding $A$ matrix...

Comment: Wow you're right, I forgot for a second, the coefficients are not constant, the EVD does not work like in the constant case, because always a new term arises from coefficients itself. For example if old system equation is $\dot X=AX$ and we put $Y=U^TX$ where $A=U\Lambda U^T$ to get the new coordinates, then $\dot Y = \dot U^TX+U^T\dot X$ while in constant coefficient case we only have $\dot Y = U^T\dot X$ and new system becomes $\dot Y = \Lambda Y$! BTW you have the explicit answer to $x,y$ in terms of $t$, is decoupling more important than the answer? Are you trying to conclude something?

Comment: My Goal is to find an analytical expression for $x,y$ in terms of $t$. So the answer is more important than decoupling. If it's possile to solve the system without decoupling, that's perfectly fine.

Basically $x,y,z$ are coordinates which describe a quantum state on a (bloch - ) sphere. I'm interested in the time evolution of the state under given dissipative processes which lead to the equations at hand. 

In a next step I would have to do another transformation:
$$x = \cos (\omega t) \tilde{x} - \sin (\omega t) \tilde{y}\\
y = \cos (\omega t) \tilde{y} + \sin (\omega t) \tilde{x}
$$

Comment: The ($\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}, \tilde{z}$) basis would then represent the laboratory frame in which I want to describe the system. I found it quite interesting, that the transformation you found from the EDV almost gave the transformation I have to do anyways...
 In the end I hope to see the coordinates evolving in a stationary state which doesn't change any further in $t$.

Comment: Okay then, if the solution is more important, I already solved the system in the first part of answer. I obtained  $x = \frac{(a+b)t}{2} - \frac{a}{4\omega}\cos(2\omega t) - \frac{a}{8\omega}\sin(4\omega t) + c'$ as a function of time with $c'$ the constant of integration. $y$ can also be obtained after substituting $x$ in one of the equations.